# Why might a share price have not changed for several days?

Tags: canada, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, shares

I own some shares in a large (~$10 billion) company. I've been keeping an eye on the share price for several weeks as I'm looking to sell them in the next few months.

In the last few days however (since the 17th), the share price has remained static and no new information has been added.

What might be the cause for this?

Comment: We could give you a better answer if we knew what company.

Comment: Fairfax Finacial Holdings Ltd.

Answer (score 10):

It is because 17th was Friday, 18th-19th were weekends and 20th was a holiday on the [Toronto Stock Exchange (Family Day)](https://www.tsx.com/trading/calendars-and-trading-hours/calendar-and-events). Just to confirm you could have picked up another stock trading on TMX and observed the price movements.